# CSS - Workflow pages are off

Tags: workflow, css, branding, quick-launch

So I have a custom CSS for my SharePoint site and everything is fine except for the Workflow page - for example, the page where you enter the names of people who to route the document for the approval workflow.

Anyone know what CSS tags should be modified to move items on this page around? I have the Quicklaunch hidden on some of my pages but on the Workflow I cannot edit the page to add a Content Editor and I am not too sure how to just target the Workflow pages in the regular CSS.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There maybe many ways to do this, but maybe using jQuery to locate an unique HTML element on the workflow page and the apply the custom CSS is the most flexible one:

1. include jQuery to your page;
2. choose a HTML element on your workflow page as the "identifier" of your page. for example, you can choose the "start" button on the bottom of your page, it should have an ID property with value like this "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_XmlFormControl_V1_I1_B10".
3. in the $(document).ready function, use

> if($(‘#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_XmlFormControl_V1_I1_B10’).length>0){/*use jQuery to apply your costom CSS.*/}

it should work, good luck!

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, well I think my issue is just CSS related as its just the page where you fill in who the approval workflow forwards a document to. So its just sitting a bit off on the right side...it overflows onto the side since the site is a fixed width site. I have found these this class .ms-bodyareacell {} and tried just moving it to the left, it work but this move everything on the whole site to the left a bit, how can I just target the workflow pages? Since all my libraries use the approval workflow......

Comment: Got it, I just updated my answer, hope this time it helps :)